# Number Theory problem modulo 7

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Going from $z^2+z+1\equiv 0\pmod{7^3}$, knowing that $z=7w+2$, arrive to $7w^2+5w+1\equiv 0\pmod {7^2}$

I don't see how these to equations are related... Could someone help me passing from the first to the second?

Comment: Do you mean $z=7w+2$?

Comment: i got $z=18$ or $z=324$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with

$$z^2+z+1\equiv 0\mod 343$$

$$(7w+2)^2+(7w+2)+1\equiv 0\mod 343$$

$$49w^2+35w+7\equiv 0\mod 343$$

Let $7w^2+5w+1=n$. Since

$$7n\equiv 0\mod 343$$

we have that

$$7n = 343k$$

for some integer $k$.

$$n = 49k$$

$$n\equiv 0\mod 49$$

$$7w^2+5w+1\equiv 0\mod 7^2$$

Comment: Didn't you mean $\equiv 0$ in the last line?